# Populating a ListView with random data

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

Here is my fragment's `onCreateView` :

```
`

        String[] pelda = {
                "12345",
                "blabla",
                "hhahho",
        };

        List<String> elorejelzes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(pelda));
         elorejelzesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.lista_elem_elorejelzes,
                R.id.lista_elem_elorejelzes_textview,
                 elorejelzes);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_idojaras_kijelzo, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(elorejelzesAdapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_idojaras_kijelzo, container, false);
```

I don't get any errors, I also verified, and the `Activity` starts the `fragment` correctly.

Here is my `fragment` `XML` code:

**fragment_idojaras_kijelzo**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Comment: You didn't write the issue

Comment: what you exactly want ? Please specify.

Comment: why do you return return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_idojaras_kijelzo, container, false) instead of rootView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is that the ListView doesn't show up.

This is most likely because you're not returning the view that you're inflating and manipulating.

You inflate the first view, and find the listview on that, and set the adapter (which is all correct), but then you inflate a new view and return that.. You need to return the view you're manipulating. I've shown this below in the code.

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_idojaras_kijelzo, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(elorejelzesAdapter);
    return rootView;
```